# How to take the sample out of a impulse function

Tags: signal, signal-processing, matlab, sampling

I have a system which is built from taking the transfer function.

Lets call it `"sys"`.

Now I found the impulse response for this system by taking,

```
impulse(sys)
```

I could do `(y,x) = impulse(sys)` to get the sample values out of this impulse waveform.

But these sample time are fixed, and I am looking for getting the samples out of this impulse waveform at specific sampling intervals, example: 1/100.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

From https://es.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/impulse.html "impulse(sys,t) uses the user-supplied time vector t for simulation".

So, just generate your vector as [0:dt:Tfinal] and simulate!

If your system is a rational transfer function, an alternative way would be to compute the residues [r,p,k] = residue(b,a) and just write the time-domain function taking the inverse Laplace transform using whatever time vector you wish.